# MaterializeCSS Angular2 Textfield color

Tags: css, angular, materialize

How can I change the color of a textfield in Materialize for example when the input is wrong?

I know I can do it with

```
.input-field {
     color:red;
   }
```

something.

But this applies all the time. I'm working with Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a boolean to a class:

```
<input class="foo bla bar {{valid?'valid':'invalid'}}" type="text"/>
```

This way, your input field will have `valid` or `invalid` class enabled, based on a boolean.

Then you can connect this boolean to a formControl or your own validity check based on the input value.